# mermaid-cli figure generation is very slow

Tags: javascript, performance, puppeteer, mermaid

I'm thinking of moving from `graphviz` to `mermaid` for my diagram sketches because of some mermaid feature which is not available in `graphviz`. I downloaded `mermaid-cli`, and with a custom `puppeteerConfigFile` (    `{"executablePath":  "/usr/bin/chromium"},`), it works.

the `mermaid_test.mmd` file:

```
sequenceDiagram
 A-->B: Works!
```

the command I run

```
time mmdc -i mermaid_test.mmd -o output.pdf --puppeteerConfigFile puppeteerConfigFile.json
```

the output:

```
Generating single mermaid chart

real    0m18,590s
user    0m0,946s
sys 0m0,348s
```

However, it is extremely slow, generating any kind of figure takes around 18 seconds. I had the suspicion that this is due to `mmdc` starting a new browser for every call, which [seems to be the case](https://github.com/orgs/mermaid-js/discussions/4806).

But still, is this time normal/to be expected?  I have basically no experience with JS/puppeteer, and I couldn't really find any github tickets or SO discussions related to speed, but I think not, because this is unbearable. When I start chromium itself it also starts pretty much instantly.

Any ideas what is going on here, and how I can make mermaid-cli faster?